# React refresh user data on every page load

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm having an issue figuring out something in a React app I'm working on. When a user logs in, it stores information about the user like their name, and their roles. Using this we're displaying the user's name, and obviously using their roles to show or hide components.

The problem I'm having trouble figuring out is that if the User's name changes, or their role changes while they're logged in, the information doesn't update. Now I could just refresh the data every time the user edit's their own profile, but what if an admin user edit's the logged in user's name or roles? It won't update until next login.

I thought about using `withRouter` and doing `history.listen` and updating the users information every page load on the base `App.js`. The problem I see with this is that it often gets called twice with a `REPLACE` and then a `PUSH`, so I don't want to make 2 API calls.

Is there a way I can only make 1 API call from a route change? How should I go about doing this? Am I even approaching this properly? Is there maybe a better way to fix this problem? I can't seem to find anything to help me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom Route component that calls the API on every redirect. Look at this https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow. In this example, the "PrivateRoute" component is used to check if the user is authed on every request. You could create a UpdateUserRoute component to call the API and check for changes in the user's data.

Comment: Didn't really think of doing it that way. I already need to create a `PrivateRoute` component so this should work perfectly!

Comment: Yeah and if you only wanted to make 1 call inside your private route, you wouldn't have to call "isAuthed" and then "getUserData". You could just call "getUserData" and that should tell you if you are authed as well as return the user's info.